# How to find difference in mean using MCMCregress command?

Tags: r, mcmc

I am trying to figure out how to find the difference in means for two categorical variables using MCMCregress and to plot the densities.

My code is

```
library(MCMCpack)
data("crabs") 
out <- MCMCregress(sex~sp , data = data, family=binomial)
summary(out)
```

I keep getting the error message-

```
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the `sex` variable is a `factor`. You can simple convert the `factor` to `numeric` and your code will work. Here is the code,

```
library(MCMCpack)
data("crabs") 
out <- MCMCregress(as.numeric(sex)~sp , data = crabs, family=binomial)
summary(out)

Iterations = 1001:11000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 1 
Sample size per chain = 10000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

                  Mean      SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
(Intercept)  1.5002783 0.05052 0.0005052      0.0005052
spO         -0.0003147 0.07202 0.0007202      0.0007202
sigma2       0.2551607 0.02597 0.0002597      0.0002637

2. Quantiles for each variable:

               2.5%      25%        50%     75%  97.5%
(Intercept)  1.4016  1.46639  1.5005847 1.53420 1.5996
spO         -0.1433 -0.04842 -0.0009755 0.04696 0.1420
sigma2       0.2091  0.23688  0.2534471 0.27180 0.3105
```

Comment: Ok thank you, it worked. Can you explain it to me further?

Comment: @tako: `MCMCregress` proposed for linear regression with normal type error terms (e.g. for continuous outcomes), that is, the response variable has to be numeric. In your example, `sex` is a categorical variable with "M" and "F". Thus, we have to convert them to numeric, otherwise you will receive an error message. Also note that, for categorical outcomes with two categories, linear regression and logistic regression will provide same conclusion. That is `family=binomial` and `family=normal` in the above code will provide the same conclusion.

Comment: @tako: since the above code worked, please consider providing an UpVote by clicking at the up arrow next to the answer.